# Creating RightClick Menu for Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions, right-click

If some one can provide some sample articles on how to create Right Click Menu for Drives.

Here is what needed: The right click menu will contain two additional things, i.e: **Connect** and **Disconnect**. Can we make it conditional? I mean for some condition The drive will make the Connect enabled(Ideally when not connected) and when connected it will disable the connect and enable the Disconnect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a menu item (in right click menu) to expolorer for all files (\*.\*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696736/how-to-add-a-menu-item-in-right-click-menu-to-expolorer-for-all-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is all the relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144169.aspx).  Basically you want to create a COM object that implements IShellExtInit and IContextMenu.  To register it for drives you would add an entry for it under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive.  If the MSDN documentation is a bit dense there is a [detailed walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx) on CodeProject.