# How to add a menu item (in right click menu) to explorer for all files (*.*)?

Tags: windows, shell, explorer, shell-extensions

When Winrar installed, and user right click on a file, a new mune item exists: "Add to Archive..."

How can do like this for my application?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748936/creating-rightclick-menu-for-explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding a shortcut (context) menu handler.

- A [static handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#customize_verb_static) by setting it up in registry
- Or, a [fully featured dynamic handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#verb_implementation_tasks), which is a COM object implementing necessary interfaces to advertise verbs and handle their invocations

See also:

- [Choosing a Static or Dynamic Shortcut Menu Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx) on CodeProject

Answer (score 2):

You [register under `*`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/02/4179107.aspx).