# How can I create a command on Windows when I right-click it?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

I want to create an application.

It is about dealing with files and folders.

I want to create a command which will appear after right-clicking any file on Windows.

Is there any way to accomplish this by C#?

Or do I need to use a lower-leveled language to access those things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a menu item (in right click menu) to expolorer for all files (*.*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696736/how-to-add-a-menu-item-in-right-click-menu-to-expolorer-for-all-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly write Windows "shell extensions" in C# or any other .NET language. It is quite involved (have to write a Component Object Model (COM) DLL). There is a tutorial on it using the .NET 4 Framework: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need that for yourself I think that a quick way to obtain that is to put a link to your program into the [SendTo folder](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NetworkAdmin/NetworkAdmin6.asp).

**Update**: Otherwise, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx) is a c# code sample that shows how to add the registry key.

Comment: He wants a custom context menu item and action to appear when he right clicks. He doesn't want to send a file to an application.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do everything you are trying to do with simple registry changes. Do a Google search for "Explorer right click context menu."

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the visual studio thing then I'm assuming you want to deploy your app and make the installer sort out the context menu stuff. read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx