# Integrate application in contextMenu on Windows 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7, vb.net-2010

I would like to add my app to the context menu on Windows 7 for all kind of files only, but not for the folder. How to do so ?
I just need the file path. I've started with a module to get the args

```
Module modMain

 Public Sub Main()
    If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    frmMain.display(My.Application.CommandLineArgs)
    frmMain.ShowDialog()
 End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Registry key `HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`.  Writing context menu handlers in a managed language is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: This article may help get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a menu item (in right click menu) to expolorer for all files (\*.\*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696736/how-to-add-a-menu-item-in-right-click-menu-to-expolorer-for-all-files)