# Add WPF to right click menu of some file type

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I am developing a WPF application (C#) for Windows 7. I want to add my WPF application in right click menu for some file types.

It's like if you select some mp3 files and right click on it there is a option "Add to Windows Media Player List". I want to copy same behavior.

Any suggestion will really help.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "Context Menu".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696736/how-to-add-a-menu-item-in-right-click-menu-to-expolorer-for-all-files

Comment: Whatever I found seems all code in VC++.
[see here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

Just wondering can't it been done in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit old question, but it can be done via C#. It is called "context menu shell extension".

https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell

It is not so simple (shell extension needs to be registered for file types etc.), but this library simplifies the development and installation process.